# Adding options to eclipse from plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have a plugin that installed within eclipse.

Is there a way to do the following in my case :

passing a "version" argument to eclipse when calling it to just print the plugin version in standard output without launching eclipse

```
./eclipse -version
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I did this is through  calling exit in the method body after executing the required action due to -version

Answer (score 0):

Setting the eclipse.ignoreApp parameter to true in [eclipse dir]/configuration/config.ini should do the trick. For further details look here: http://www.eclipse.org/equinox/documents/quickstart-framework.php

Comment: Is there a way to do this at runtime ?

Comment: What do you exactly mean by runtime? Do you mean by passing an argument? Here you can find all Eclipse runtime options http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fruntime-options.html . -initialize (Main) looks promising.